# how to sum to large string number in python

Tags: python, string

How to sum these two large strings, if I transform to FLOAT it loses the accuracy.

```
str1= '5.123654879542658'
str2= '8.777548795426584'

str(float(string1) + float(string2))
```

Comment: yeah exactly, when you would have converted str1 into float, the last digit have been changed..... from 4 to 5...

Comment: You have several options, depending on the purpose of such exercise.  The first 2 that come to mind: (1) You can write your own long addition code (going digit by digit). (2) You can use `decimal` package and set up needed precision.

Comment: I'm sure there's a better duplicate for this, but the search is failing me at the moment.

Comment: @PM77-1 how would write dig by dig, I like that option a lot

Comment: @Peter - the same way you've been taught (or at least supposed two) in elementary school.  I would probably split strings on decimal point, create addition function  for strings with whole numbers, and then use it twice.

Comment: Oh yeah, was thinking on using for loop. Havent thoug about using split. thanks

Comment: @PM77-1 You need to be careful after splitting, say, `1.01` using that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) package is for high precision (28 places by default) maths:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> str1= '5.123654879542658'
>>> str2= '8.777548795426584'
>>> Decimal(str1) + Decimal(str2)
Decimal('13.901203674969242')
```

Update: @KarlKnechtel seems to have found a close duplicate, oh well...